# Push and Hold Functionality for Autohotkey

Tags: input, autohotkey

I have an autohotkey that accepts double clicking input no problem. I want to also add a 'Push and Hold' function as well, but I'm unable to fully iron out the issues experimenting with it continuously.

**Here's the TL;DR**

I want a single click of the middle mouse button to send an •

I want a double click of the middle mouse button to send an ▪

I want a push-and-hold of the middle mouse button to send an ◦

Link to the API: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm

```
MButton::
KeyWait, MButton
KeyWait, MButton, D T.3
if(!ErrorLevel){
Send ▪ 
}
else{
if(!ErrorLevel){
KeyWait, MButton, D T.2
Send ◦
}
else{
Send •
return
}
}

return
```

What's wrong with the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MButton::
    KeyWait, MButton, T0.3
    If !(ErrorLevel)
    { 
        Sleep, 300
        If (A_PriorHotKey = "MButton Up") ; double click
            Send ▪
        else                              ; single click
            Send •
    }
    else                                  ; push-and-hold
        Send ◦
return

MButton Up:: return
```

Comment: I was thinking about this for a while with no success. Your clever use of **MButton Up** hotkey was the solution.

Comment: I never considered MButton Up, nor would I have without your example. Thank you. This will enable me to greatly expand my hotkeys, and with it, my productivity.